# On click of button, append form, slide down and slide up on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a form element to slide down under a div on click of button contained within that div.

When you click the button again, I want the form to slideUp();

So my HTML is like

```
<div class='cell'><div class='enquiry-button'></div></div>
<div class='cell'><div class='enquiry-button'></div></div>
<div class='cell'><div class='enquiry-button'></div></div>
```

Ive tried this:

```
$( ".enquiry-button" ).click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).closest( '.cell' ).append(
        "<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
            "<form>" +
                "Your Email: <input type='text' name='email'>" +
                "First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>" +
                "<br>Last name: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
                "<br>Contact No: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
                "<br>Postcode: <input type='text' name='postcode'>" +
                "<br>Optional Comment: <input type='textarea' name='comment'>" +
                "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"+
            "</form>" +
        "</div>"
    );

    $(this).closest( '.cell' ).find(".enquiry-form:last").slideDown("slow");

});
```

But the click function fires on every single element with the class enquiry-button (As you'd expect).

Is there an easier way of doing this?

**UPDATE**

The issue was that my `<div class='cell'>` elements were being dynamically loaded by another set of JS scripts. In my main HTML file, I was calling the above click function from within a document ready. It seems the dynamic elements were not 'ready' as using `$(window).load` solves the issue.

Comment: So the problem is that it's fired on every element of the class? Why not add an `id` attribute to the desired, targeted element?

Comment: Add a class or bind using "one"? That way it's only fired once.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do. Anyway check this http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/

Comment: The <div class="cell">s are dynamically generated, so there could be 0-30 on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very near... What you missed out here, is that , once you click on a div , you are constructing a form element . Before you click the element length will be 0, after you click the length will start increasing. Based on that, you can `toggle the slider`.

```
<div class='cell'>
    <div class='enquiry-button'>Enq1</div>
</div>
<div class='cell'>
    <div class='enquiry-button'>Enq2</div>
</div>
<div class='cell'>
    <div class='enquiry-button'>Enq3</div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
    $( ".enquiry-button" ).click( function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
alert("length::"+$(this).parents('.cell').find('form').length);
if($(this).parents('.cell').find('form').length==0){
$(this).closest( '.cell' ).append(
"<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
"<form>" +
    "Your Email: <input type='text' name='email'>" +
    "First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>" +
    "<br>Last name: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
    "<br>Contact No: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
    "<br>Postcode: <input type='text' name='postcode'>" +
    "<br>Optional Comment: <input type='textarea' name='comment'>" +
    "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"+
"</form>" +
"</div>");

$(this).closest( '.cell' ).find(".enquiry-form:last").slideDown("slow");
}else{
$(this).closest( '.cell' ).find(".enquiry-form:last").slideToggle("fast");
}
});
```

Find the fiddle Here : http://jsfiddle.net/JPUTy/5/

You can see that i have an alert here , which gives the length of the form after every click, which will make it easier for you to understand what's happening in the background.

Comment: nice. I console log instead of alert and get:length::0 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1 ResultWidget.js:36
length::1

Comment: I.e. my issue is that the click event fires for every instance of .enquiry-button on the page. The form then opens and closes in quick succession like a snapping alligator. So my issue is something else.

Comment: This is correct, click event is firing for every instance of the click, as you have `$( ".enquiry-button" )` wrapped in a click function, which is valid. Can be a little clear as to what you are expecting ?

Comment: This is the effect I'm currently getting (i've modified the code, as in the fiddle it works fine) http://jsfiddle.net/GMjNS/3/ . I think I'll have to try and work out what else is going on in my DOM. :)

Comment: Your logic is wrong, you have used a `while` loop here. That's why it's fading in and out as iterations are being performed for 9 times. Ok, lemme have a look at that. Anyways, can you tell me , when you want the slide up to happen and when u want the slide down to happen ?

Comment: haha. Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself. The while loop is just in the Fiddle to give an example of whats happening in my code. I don't have a while loop in my actual code.

Comment: @Kiksy : okay, hope you get what you are looking for .

Comment: Choosing this answer, even though many are correct. I didn't give enough info in my question, but the console.log helped me hunt down the issue.

Comment: @Kiksy - note that this will not work if you have 0 elements at the start, then add one or more RE: your comment on the question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you do not add another, but toggle the slide on third click?  Need to hide the new form to allow the `slideDown`, cache the cell selector for reuse.

```
$(".enquiry-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var cell = $(this).closest('.cell');
    if (cell.find('.enquiry-form').length) {
        cell.find('.enquiry-form').slideToggle();
    } else {
        cell.append(
            "<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
            "<form>" +
            "Your Email: <input type='text' name='email'>" +
            "First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>" +
            "<br>Last name: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
            "<br>Contact No: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
            "<br>Postcode: <input type='text' name='postcode'>" +
            "<br>Optional Comment: <input type='textarea' name='comment'>" +
            "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>" +
            "</form>" +
            "</div>");
        cell.find('.enquiry-form').hide().slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

sample in action: http://jsfiddle.net/GMjNS/

NOTE per late comment, if you use dynamic elements, change the first line to:

`$(document).on("click", ".enquiry-button", function (e) {`

If you have 0 elements, it will not have a clickable item so that should be OK.  Note that you should NOTE bind to the document but instead use a closer wrapper (like a div wrapper etc.) to bind to: example

`$('#mywrapperelementid').on("click", ".enquiry-button", function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

Check wether the clicked element's parent has a form child or not, if it has, `slideToggle()` !

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/uSQR2/)

### JavaScript/JQuery

```
$(".enquiry-button").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (!$(this).parents('.cell').find('form').length) {
        $(this).closest('.cell').append(
            "<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
            "<form>" +
            "Your Email: <input type='text' name='email'>" +
            "First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>" +
            "<br>Last name: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
            "<br>Contact No: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
            "<br>Postcode: <input type='text' name='postcode'>" +
            "<br>Optional Comment: <input type='textarea' name='comment'>" +
            "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>" +
            "</form>" +
            "</div>");


        $(this).closest('.cell').find(".enquiry-form:last").slideDown("slow");
    } else $(this).closest('.cell').find(".enquiry-form:last").slideToggle("slow");


});
```

### CSS

```css
.enquiry-form {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class to `.cell` after first click and remove class after second click:

```
    $(".enquiry-button").click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent();

            if (!$parent.hasClass('opened')) {

                if (!$parent.find('form').length) {
                    $parent.append('<form>Input: <input type="text"/></form>');
                }

                $parent.addClass('opened');
            } else {
                $parent.removeClass('opened');
            }
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uNwLn/

Answer (score 0):

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7rxD/1/) if you only want one form opened at the time.

jQuery:

```
$('.enquiry-button').click(function(e){
    $('.cell .enquiry-form:visible').slideUp('slow', function(){
         $(this).remove();
    });

    if( $(this).parent('.cell').hasClass('active') )
    {
        $(this).parent('.cell').removeClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.cell').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('.cell').addClass('active');

        $('.cell.active').append("<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
    "<form>" +
    "Your Email: <input type='text' name='email'>" +
    "First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>" +
    "<br>Last name: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
    "<br>Contact No: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
    "<br>Postcode: <input type='text' name='postcode'>" +
    "<br>Optional Comment: <input type='textarea' name='comment'>" +
    "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"+
    "</form>" +
"</div>");

        $('.cell.active .enquiry-form').hide().slideDown('slow');
    }
});
```