# Javascript not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im playing around with some code from this thread [On click of button, append form, slide down and slide up on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231274/on-click-of-button-append-form-slide-down-and-slide-up-on-second-click)

When I start the server and go to my localhost in the browser the javascript will not work.  All text displays fine, but the javascript isn't working.  Any ideas as to why this is?

http://jsfiddle.net/JPUTy/16/

script.js

```
 $(".enquiry-button").click(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

     if (!$(this).parents('.cell').find('form').length) {
         $(this).closest('.cell').append(
             "<div class='enquiry-form'>" +
             "<form>" +
             "Your Email: <input type='text' name='email'>" +
             "First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>" +
             "<br>Last name: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
             "<br>Contact No: <input type='text' name='lastname'>" +
             "<br>Postcode: <input type='text' name='postcode'>" +
             "<br>Optional Comment: <input type='textarea' name='comment'>" +
             "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>" +
             "</form>" +
             "</div>");


         $(this).closest('.cell').find(".enquiry-form:last").slideDown("slow");
     } else $(this).closest('.cell').find(".enquiry-form:last").slideToggle("slow");


 });
```

css

```
 .enquiry-form {
     display:none;
 }
```

home.html.erb

```
 <div class='cell'>
     <div class='enquiry-button'>asd</div>
 </div>
 <div class='cell'>
      <div class='enquiry-button'>asd</div>
 </div>
 <div class='cell'>
      <div class='enquiry-button'>asd</div>
 </div>
```

application.js

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require_self
 //= require_tree .
```

Comment: Check that you call scripts after your elements defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails javascripts are loaded in the header of the page, so your js code is loaded before your element appear, an example in jsfiddle (that doesn't work) will look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JPUTy/17/

what you can do about it is to wrap your js into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

so your code will load only after the whole document is loaded. Example that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/JPUTy/18/

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  Not much of a JS guy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using turbolinks so `$(document).ready` won't work 'out of the box'. You can use [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem to make it work.